# Ruby Fuzzily relation "trigrams" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to use the Ruby gem Fuzzily in my rails application, but am getting this error

```
relation "trigrams" does not exist
```

I followed all the instructions from https://github.com/mezis/fuzzily

Here's my code

trigram.rb

```
class Trigram < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Url::Model
  include Fuzzily::Model
end
```

url.rb

```
class Url < ActiveRecord::Base
    fuzzily_searchable :short_url
end
```

add_trigram_mode.rb

```
class AddTrigramsModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  extend Url::Migration
  extend Fuzzily::Migration

  trigrams_owner_id_column_type = :uuid

end
```

I did a rake db:migrate.  When I execute this in rails console, I get:

```
    Url.find_by_fuzzy_short_url('sojdgl')

 Url Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "urls".* FROM "urls"  ORDER BY "urls"."id" ASC LIMIT 100
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "trigrams" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"trigrams"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"trigrams"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "trigrams" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"trigrams"'::regclass
```

Comment: I did a rake db:migrate.  What exactly is it supposed to do?  What should I look for?

Comment: I renamed the migration to what you said and now get this error NameError: uninitialized constant AddTrigramModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I named the migration file incorrectly.  I works when I changed it to 20150830110623_add_trigrams_model.rb